# Native GBA Emulation

Tags: emulation

Since the GBA and the Pi both have ARM processors, would it be possible to natively run GBA roms, as long as a wrapper is created to control the GPU, sound, etc, or would the CPU still have to be emulated? If it is possible, would it have to be done OS-less or is it possible within Linux?